# counting holes in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays

So I have an 2d array named wall[R][C].

What I'm trying to do here is that I'll subtract 1 from integer named hole whenever I see 2's that are next to each other in the array.

Specifically in wall[R-2][0]~wall[R-2][C-3](in the row), wall[0][C-2]~wall[R-3][C-2](in the column), I'll check for a 2 coming next to another 2.

I know it is hard to understand what I'm saying, so I'll show you an example.

1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2

1  2  2  2  1  1  2  2

1  2  2  2  1  1  1  1

1  2  2  2  1  2  2  1

1  1  1  1  2  2  2  1

1  0  0  0  1  1  2  1

1  0  1  0  1  1  2  1

1  0  0  0  1  1  2  1

In this array, I'd check for the elements in the * box and @ box.

In *box, I'll check if the element is 2, and if it is, I'll check if the element right below that 2 is also 2.

In @ box, I'll check for the element next to it.

Everytime I find that, I'll subtract one from integer hole.

At wall[R-2][C-2], it might get subtracted 2 times if both the upper element and left element is 2.

I wouldn't want that so I add 1 to hole if that happens.

1 1 1 1 1 1*2*2

1 2 2 2 1 1*2*2

1 2 2 2 1 1*1*1

1 2 2 2 1 2*2*1

1 1 1 1 2 2*2*1

1 0 0 0 1 1*2*1

@ @ @ @ @

1 0 1 0 1 1@ 2 1

@ @ @ @ @

1 0 0 0 1 1 2 1

So I wrote the code, but it give me the wrong result.

I expected it would subract 4 from hole.

But it subtracts 7.

I've been working too long, so it's really hard for me to see what is wrong with this code.

please help me find what is wrong.

```
for(int i=0;i<R-2;i++){

    if(wall[i][C-2]==2&&wall[i+1][C-2]==2)  hole--;

}

for(int i=0;i<C-2;i++){

    if(wall[R-2][i]-=2&&wall[R-2][i+1]==2)  hole--;

}

if(wall[R-2][C-2]==2&&wall[R-2][C-3]==2&&wall[R-3][C-2]==2)   hole++; //this is for preventing double subtraction.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your if statement, `if(wall[R-2][i]-=2&&wall[R-2][i+1]==2)  hole--;`,

you have `-=` not `==`, I changed that and it was giving me -4 as you expected.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't see that all this time... Thank you so much